# How to remove host information from transcript data from PowerShell output

Tags: powershell

Running a PowerShell script from a task scheduler and which is writing the `transcript` data to a log file. But it is including the host information and output from the PowerShell. Don't want to include the host information in the log file is there any way to do it?

Tried to use `-UseMinimalHeader` but not working.

```
function DatabaseAutomationService() {

    $URL  = 'http://localhost:9096/health';
   
    Start-Transcript -Path "G:\AutomationService\database_automation.log" -Append -IncludeInvocationHeader
    try  {
    $health_URL_Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method Get
    $StatusCode = $Response.StatusCode
        if ($health_URL_Response -match "OK") {
            Write-Host "Health Service is running fine !!!!"
        }
    }
    catch {
            Write-Host 'The service is not running, you need to start the service !!!';
            $listAllService = cmd.exe /c pm2 list
            $triggerDBAutomation =  cmd.exe /c pm2 start "C:\AutomationService\executionservice.js" --name "AutomationService"
               if($?) {
                Write-Host "Service Started successfully !!!"
               }
    }
    Stop-Transcript
}
DatabaseAutomationService
```

Output:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230130093640
Username: PerfUser
RunAs User: PerfUser
Machine: SQLServer1001 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -File G:\AutomationService\AutomationHelper.ps1
Process ID: 28508
PSVersion: 5.1.14393.5582
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14393.5582
BuildVersion: 10.0.14393.5582
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is G:\AutomationService\database_automation.log
Health Service is running fine !!!!
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20230130093640
**********************
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230130093643
Username: PerfUser
RunAs User: PerfUser
Machine: SQLServer1001 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -File G:\AutomationService\AutomationHelper.ps1
Process ID: 23940
PSVersion: 5.1.14393.5582
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14393.5582
BuildVersion: 10.0.14393.5582
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is G:\AutomationService\database_automation.log
Health Service is running fine !!!!
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20230130093643
**********************
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230130103000
Username: PerfUser
RunAs User: PerfUser
Machine: SQLServer1001 (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -File G:\AutomationService\AutomationHelper.ps1
Process ID: 8072
PSVersion: 5.1.14393.5582
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14393.5582
BuildVersion: 10.0.14393.5582
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is G:\AutomationService\database_automation.log
Health Service is running fine !!!!
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20230130103000
**********************
**********************
```

Want to write only the following,

[image]

Comment: [-UseMinimalHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript#-useminimalheader)?

Comment: `-UseMinimalHeader` tried with this but I am not able to remove all the data from header.

Comment: Add following to end of command to suppress any unwanted output : | Out-Null